# Ubuntu 20.04 mouse glitch at edge of screen

Tags: 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, mouse

I recently moved from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and am using a USB display docking station with 2 extra monitors on my Lenovo laptop (E580). The problem is that when I move the mouse to the right side of my leftmost screen the mouse appears at the same point on the screen next to it. It also glitches.

The funny thing is that when I change the order of the screens in the Ubuntu settings this doesn't happen. It seems like Ubuntu is  not sure on what screen the mouse actually is in that region.

I used 2 different drivers for the docking station and the behavior was the same.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Laptop: Lenovo E580
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
- Docking station: i-tec USB 3.0 / USB-C / Thunderbolt 3 Dual Display Docking Station +
  Power Delivery 85W

Comment: A silly question you say The funny thing is that when I change the order of the screens in the Ubuntu settings this doesn't happen is there a reason you can not leave it the way it works?

Comment: I can't change the physical order of my monitors, because the leftmost monitor is connected to other things too

Comment: OK you did say you had changed it and it worked.

Comment: You could switch the connectors on the docking station.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was, but I enabled Wayland in the login screen and now it works normally.